# Async function not waiting for results even when used inside useEffect with await

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code  within a component where I am using a cookie value to decide which component or div block to show.

This works eventually as expected. But there is a short while where it seems like the cookie value is not checked yet.

During this period, I keep entering the `else` block first. After a couple of seconds, I enter the `if` block correctly.

But why? That `Cookies.get` is an async call. But I am calling it inside `useEffect` and using await.

Could I please know how I could modify this so that if the cookie is existing, I will never enter the else block?

```
import React from 'react';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const Sample = () => {
  const [cookie, setCookie] = React.useState(false);
  const hasCookie = async () => !!Cookies.get('my-cookie');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const myCookie = async () => await hasCookie();
    myCookie().then((result) => setCookie(result));
  }, []);

  const component = () => {
    if (cookie) {
      console.log(`YES there is a cookie: ${cookie}`);
      return <div>
        Yup the cookie exists
      </div>;
    } else {
      console.log(`NO no cookie: ${cookie}`);
      return <div>
        Nope no cookie
      </div>;
    }
  };

  return component();
};

export default Sample;
```

For reference the following is the console log where it prints false for while before turning to true.

```
Sample.jsx:20 NO no cookie: false
Sample.jsx:20 NO no cookie: false
Sample.jsx:20 NO no cookie: false
Sample.jsx:20 NO no cookie: false
Sample.jsx:20 NO no cookie: false
Sample.jsx:20 NO no cookie: false
Sample.jsx:20 NO no cookie: false
Sample.jsx:20 NO no cookie: false
Sample.jsx:20 NO no cookie: false
Sample.jsx:15 YES there is a cookie: true
Sample.jsx:15 YES there is a cookie: true
Sample.jsx:15 YES there is a cookie: true
....
```

Comment: `Cookies.get` doesn't appear to be asynchronous or to return a promise. Wrapping it in `async` will just make it a promise that executes the `then` clause instantly.

Comment: @DanMonego If I just call like if(Cookies.get('my-cookie')) {} , outcome is the same where it is false for awhile and then true. If it is not async would have thought it should be true from the start.

Comment: You're getting the same outcome because putting async/await around a non async function does the same thing. [There's nothing async about that function](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/blob/main/src/api.mjs#L50-L74). Your application is setting the cookie sometime after render. If it's important that this component never show without cookies in place, you can do that the hard way inside the component or the easy way somewhere in the stack that knows about the cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all there is something that may be a future problem:

Because `Cookies.get('my-cookie')` returns a Promise, it's an object. Using `!!` on objects always returns true (objects are truthy).

So `hasCookie` should always return true?

To make it properly test if it exists you should `await` the Promise until it resolves, then use `!!` on the resolved value:

```js
!!(await Cookies.get('my-cookie'));
```

To answer your question, the most common way is a state that tracks if something is loading:

```js
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
```

When it is loading, you return something else:

```js
if (loading) return null; // if you don't want to render anything
```

Otherwise you can continue as normal.

When you set the cookie, also make sure to set loading to false:

```js
setCookie(result);
setLoading(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are manipulating asynchronous data, having a loader will be an easy way to resolve your problem:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const Sample = () => {
  const [cookie, setCookie] = React.useState(false);
  const [checking, setChecking] = React.useState(true);
  const hasCookie = async () => !!Cookies.get('my-cookie');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const myCookie = async () => await hasCookie();
    myCookie().then((result) => {
     setCookie(result);
      setChecking(false)
    });
  }, []);

  const component = () => {
    if(checking){
     return <p>Loading...</p>
    }
    if (cookie) {
      console.log(`YES there is a cookie: ${cookie}`);
      return <div>
        Yup the cookie exists
      </div>;
    } else {
      console.log(`NO no cookie: ${cookie}`);
      return <div>
        Nope no cookie
      </div>;
    }
  };

  return component();
};

export default Sample;
```